# Observable collection deep copy

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a uniform grid in this application. After resizing the window (when width<300) it removes the right column from the grid, and change `IsEnabled=false` items. After reverting to the previous size (width>300), it adds back the deleted column and its elements. But is seems not working.After reverting element still `IsEnabled=false` Why?

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Cars cars;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            cars = new Cars();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = cars;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CarType> temp;

        public bool Crutch;
        private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewSize.Width<300)
            {
                if (cars.Items.Count == 4)
                {
                    cars.Columns = 1;
                    cars.Rows = 2;
                    temp = new ObservableCollection<CarType>(from x in cars.Items select (CarType)x.Clone());           
                    cars.Items.ToList().GetRange(2, 2).ForEach(x => x.IsEnabled = false);
                    Crutch = true;
                }
            }
            if (e.NewSize.Width>300)
            {
                if (Crutch)
                {
                    cars.Items = temp;
                    cars.Columns = 2;
                    cars.Rows = 2;
                    Crutch = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class CarType:ICloneable,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }

        public bool isEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled 
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isEnabled;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChaged("IsEnabled");
            }
        }
        public CarType()
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChaged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return new CarType { number=this.number,IsEnabled=this.IsEnabled,date=this.date,comments=this.comments};
        }
    }
    public class Cars:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int rows;

        private int columns;
        public int Rows 
        { 
            get
            {
                return this.rows;
            }

            set
            {
                this.rows = value;
                RaisePropertyChaged("Rows");
            }
        }
        public int Columns
        {
            get
            {
                return this.columns;
            }

            set
            {
                this.columns = value;
                RaisePropertyChaged("Columns");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<CarType> items;
        public ObservableCollection<CarType> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.items;
            }

            set
            {
                this.items = value;
                RaisePropertyChaged("Items");
            }
        }
        public Cars()
        {
            Rows = 2;
            Columns = 2;
            Items = new ObservableCollection<CarType>();
            Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date  =DateTime.Now, number = 1 });
            Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date = DateTime.Now, number = 2 });
            Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date = DateTime.Now, number = 3 });
            Items.Add(new CarType { comments = "First", date = DateTime.Now, number = 4 });
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChaged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="500" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
<Canvas>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Columns}" Rows="{Binding Rows}"></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid Width="200" Height="100" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding number}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding date}"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding comments}"></Label>
                </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window's `SizeChanged` event is fired **repeatedly** whenever you resize the window, you may expect it to be fired only once when its size is "finalized" (when you stop resizing the window), but that is not correct.

So this line is called repeatedly when you widening the window from narrower than 300 to wider than 300.

```
temp = new ObservableCollection<CarType>(from x in cars.Items select (CarType)x.Clone());
```

So you are making deep copy of CarTypes with IsEnabled=False.

**And to answer your question in your comment "how to make right copy":**

You can make an **original copy**, and then use a copy of the original copy when you need to re-enable the Grids.

```
ObservableCollection<CarType> originalCopy;
public MainWindow()
{
    cars = new Cars();
    originalCopy = new ObservableCollection<CarType>(from x in cars.Items select (CarType)x.Clone());
    ....
}
```

And when you need this copy of original copy:

```
if (e.NewSize.Width>300)
{
    if (Crutch)
    {
        cars.Items = new ObservableCollection<CarType>(from x in originalCopy select (CarType)x.Clone());
```

In this way your original copy is intact (their IsEnbled property is always True).

**But...**

I would suggest you do not use the "copy",  use only one `ItemSource` (cars.Items), and change the `IsEnabled` property accordingly. Copy items and then re-bind later does not make much sense.

I mean (other code are removed for better explanation)

```
if (e.NewSize.Width < 300)
{
    cars.Items.ToList().GetRange(2, 2).ForEach(x => x.IsEnabled = false);
}
else //e.NewSize.Width >= 300
{
    cars.Items.ToList().GetRange(2, 2).ForEach(x => x.IsEnabled = true);
}
```